# Typescript: Check if object has property and check property value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type guard by checking if an object has a property and then proceed to check if it equals a certain value:

```
const isJson = (myObject: unknown): myObject is Json => {
  return Boolean(
    myObject && typeof myObject === 'object' && 'type' in myObject && myObject.type === 'something'
  );
};
```

This will fail: `Property 'type' does not exist on type 'object'`.
Please note that it only fails when trying to build the project, otherwise typescript will be fine with the above code.

The only solution I could think of is to separate the check into two stages which isn't very neat:

```
const isJson = (myObject: unknown): myObject is Json => {
  const hasType = (myObject: unknown): myObject is { [key: string]: unknown; type: unknown } => {
    return Boolean(myObject && typeof myObject === 'object' && 'type' in myObject);
  };
  if (!hasType(myObject)) {
    return false;
  }

  return Boolean(myObject.type === 'something');
};
```

This will work. Is there a better and simpler way?

My tsconfig settings:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
```

Comment: [I can't replicate that error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHZQLxQN6kgLigIkQFsJgALASyQHN8BfAbgCgmBjZOYKCueZNKAAoiIAPIAjAFYRWwPAFckAayQIA7kgCUeEROmzucWIhSoAfJiZRrUAE6l5tlACEECADYQAhkkFWbAbpSMlwAZKFQ2BAIAGZQQfpcqMkECMGy+FDhBFGZVPFi6WERCSEAdFFoKYQIJORUtP7WmsyMQA). What are your tsconfig settings? Though I can't immediately think of one that would give you that error given your `"type" in myObject` check...

Comment: FWIW, you can avoid the call to `Boolean`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHZQLxQN6kgLigIkQFsJgALASyQHN8BfAbgCgmBjZOYKCueZNKAAoiIAPIAjAFYRWwPAFckAayQIA7kgCUeEROmzucWIhSoAfJiZRrUAE6l5tlNggIAZlF1SZXVH4II3rL4UABkoVY2UV76XACE-kjyADbJYRFRUfguIVSeYkFc4ZGZ+Xo+AHQuaP6ECCTkVLTMjEA

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr9yzw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am i missing?

Comment: @wonderflame - Can you replicate the error? As far as I can see, the OP's original code compiles just fine.

Comment: (Side note: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [More here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript or TypeScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. So that `Json` type seems suspect...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, no, I couldn't replicate it, just proposed a nicer approach in my opinion. With my approach you are not forced to check every field with `in` operator

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your reply, I just updated my tsconfig settings

Comment: @wonderflame Thank you very much, it looks good, but it still separates into two stages but probably there's no other way around it so it's good enough and interesting approach thanks again

Comment: Oh sorry didn't hit 'update' now it's there

Comment: I guess it's all expected then, should I delete the question?

Comment: @sir-haver there is no type-safe way of doing that with just only 1 operation, to be honest

Comment: If you are okay with your current type guard and if you are not looking for some different approach then let's delete the question, otherwise I can post the answer if you prefer

Comment: Oh I see, yes please if you can post it as an answer and I will gladly accept

Comment: @sir-haver - [Even with those settings, I can't replicate the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHZQLxQN6kgLigIkQFsJgALASyQHN8BfAbgCgmBjZOYKCueZNKAAoiIAPIAjAFYRWwPAFckAayQIA7kgCUeEROmzucWIhSoAfJiZRrUAE6l5tlACEECADYQAhkkFWbAbpSMlwAZKFQ2BAIAGZQQfpcqMkECMGy+FDhBFGZVPFi6WERCSEAdFFoKYQIJORUtP7WmsyMQA). Please provide an [mre].

Comment: @T.J.Crowder tbh it will be too much of a hassle to reproduce it, it's in a big nx project

Comment: Then please just delete the question. There's no point in having a question on the site that cannot be answered.

Comment: or you can change the focus of the question from solving the error to finding a better approach for type guards

Comment: Yes that was what I asked, was a bit in a conflict(: I will just keep it in the hope that it can benefit someone who bumps into the same issue
Thanks a lot again to both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach, we can create a type guard that checks if the argument is any object.

```
const isObject = <T>(arg: unknown): arg is T => {
  return !!arg && typeof arg === 'object' && !Array.isArray(arg);
};
```

We are going to pass some object `T`, which will be inferred as the type of the `arg` if `arg` is not falsy and it's not an array, and it's type is `object`.

The reason to pass the `T` is to avoid `as` assertion afterward, however, if we pass the desired type directly to `isObject`, this won't be absolutely type-safe since we won't need to check the properties of the object for the existence/correctness. Instead of passing the final type we will modify our type with the following utility:

```
type PartialUnknown<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: unknown;
};
```

This will make all fields optional and type them as `unknown`. With this, we won't have to use `in` operator to remove the error with the key not being in the object. The rest is pretty straightforward, just check the type of the fields and you are ready to go.

Usage:

```
const isJson = (myObject: unknown): myObject is Json => {
  if (!isObject<PartialUnknown<Json>>(myObject)) return false;

  const { type } = myObject;

  return typeof type === 'string' && type === 'something';
};
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nr9yzw)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding a testing interface for your function parameter. Take a look at my solution.
[Playground Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0%20mM9ysygc9wASmCGQUZGSDCWAFk8AB5aQAK0gsFQOEg6rqKAA3ooSiUANrxSB4fJXVCUTjMAC6AbMeAA3IoAL7SxpUkSCABSsq8vKViEtNrtqAD5qttvtjudClAAB8xJw8DqStyAHygd0lJyofFeABC8DlHk4So9JSVoGzRbzoAAZBO0O0iaPc-aedzeQByeAL1AryfT%20fF1ABByCC0STi0NgbVB4JUry9EFc6utTkc5vcBW8oZer2XIIYhleDnUY1jGME0pakeWTNNGiVV0ZyIAMV2-SBf2YLdY0A4oZXA3khCg-sVw5WB7xAmVewVeBlT5BtqLEPkLgwlQcGaDwyC8RBxWcYF2BoL43DMZh2AYZhIH4WBoHURIOXgPQRC8Pk6QZJlBD5JJsT5cAHE3YQADlIAkPkghUC0vjId5BBErRkMDRwFFcaQ8FAJx2J0YYsH0FAEEQaFhEuXiJHFaJk1AQx8XmRgWDYLhuCCEogA)

```js
interface MyObjectTemplate {
  [key: string]: any;
}
const isJson = (myObject: MyObjectTemplate | any) => {
  return Boolean(
    (myObject && typeof myObject === 'object' && myObject.hasOwnProperty('type')) && myObject.type === 'something'
  );
};
```